# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, php7

Ошибка - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

Знаю что этот метод устареший и нужно заменить на новый, только не совсем понимаю как) кто знает help

```
static function escape($string, $hsc=false) {
    $string=stripslashes($string);
    if ($hsc) {
        $string=htmlspecialchars($string);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}

/**
 * @static Escape string and add single quotes, possibly escaping html special characters
 * @param string $string
 * @param bool $hsc
 * @return string
 */
static function escapeAndQuote($string, $hsc=false) {
    return "'" . sidb::escape($string, $hsc) . "'";
}
```

Comment: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125145/how-to-convert-mysql-real-escape-string-to-php7)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` методы считаются устаревшими, используйте `mysqli`

```
mysqli_real_escape_string
```